# F#: Trouble with loading data into SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, f#, type-providers

I am new to programming and F# is my first language.

I want to load data into a SQL Server database using F# code. Here is the table that is supposed to store my data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Scores](
    [EventName] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [Winner] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Loser] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Score1] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [Score2] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [Score3] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

`Score1`, `Score2` and `Score3` are supposed to contain judges' scores, which might be unavailable sometimes.

Here is my F# code for loading the data:

```ml
            new dbSchema.ServiceTypes.Fights(EventName = fightSummary.event,
                                            Winner = fightSummary.winner.Value,
                                            Loser = fightSummary.loser.Value,

                                            Score1 = if judgesScoresExist then
                                                        fightSummary.judgesScores.Value.[0]
                                                     else
                                                        "None",
                                            Score2 = if judgesScoresExist then
                                                        fightSummary.judgesScores.Value.[1]
                                                     else 
                                                        "None",
                                            Score3 = if judgesScoresExist then
                                                        fightSummary.judgesScores.Value.[2]
                                                     else "None")
```

When I try to run the F# code above, I receive the following error message:

> This expression was expected to have type
>       `string`
>   but here has type
>       'a * 'b

Apparently, the compiler interprets the part

```ml
"None", Score2 = ...
```

as a tuple.

I tried searching online for a solution, but have yet to find one.

What changes should I make so that I can load my data into SQL Server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put `if then else` expressions in parenthesis:

```ml
let v = new Fights(EventName = fightSummary.event,
                   Winner = fightSummary.winner.Value,
                   Loser = fightSummary.loser.Value,

                   Score1 = (if judgesScoresExist then
                               fightSummary.judgesScores.Value.[0]
                             else
                               "None"),
                    ...) // etc.
```

Comment: Now I feel stupid for not having thought of it! Thank you, Petr! :-)